# Managing Multiple Access Tokens in .NET 4.6

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am slowly learning OAuth/OICD/AzureAD/Azure B2C concepts so bear with me as I am not typically good with jargon. I am working OIDC into a legacy .NET WebForms application using AzureAD as the auth provider. In general things are are working. However, as I want to be able to consume multiple APIs I need to manage multipe access tokens. This is where I am having trouble. The standard situation is to set the Redeemcode and SaveTokens properties of OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions. This saves the id token, access token, and refresh token in what I believe is called the AuthenticationProperties object.

I am trying to use MSAL to get an access token for Microsoft Graph but I find MSAL to be confusing in how it abstracts things that seem very straight forward in other client libraries for similar things. I simply want to get an access token. My assumption was that I would exchange a refresh token, client id and client secret and scope to get an access token for Microsoft Graph. However when I try to make a call like below I always run in to a dead end. The UserAssertion accepts an access_token as one of the overloads. But which token? Shouldn't it be refresh token? If I use that it says it's malformed and I cannot view it in jwt.io as the first section of the token is blank. No matter what token I provide I get an error.

```
authenticationResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(scope, clientCredential, new UserAssertion(accessToken)).Result;
```

Can anyone offer suggestions on how to approach this? Is there a more straight forward client library to use to deal with tokens? Or is just making my own calls with an HttpClient the way to go possibly? I'm struggling with why something so common is seemingly so confusing.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, if you are trying to use MSAL to obtain an access token for Microsoft Graph, then this sample should be for you:  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapp-openidconnect

Comment: Well half my issue is resolved as I am now using IdentityModel. It just makes more sense to me. .My confusion comes with how to handle multiple access tokens. My understanding is that I would need an access token for my API and another for Graph. The initial login handles the acquisition and storage of my id, api access token, and refresh token. I am having trouble understanding how to conceptualize managing the access token for Graph or any other API I may need to call.

Comment: What sequence of flows would I use to get two access tokens on behalf of the user for different resources? I'm stumped. I must be thinking about this wrong.

Comment: Please use this reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52211990/multiple-access-tokens-with-azure-ad-b2c.